# Disk partitions became read-only

Tags: disk

I dual boot Windows 10 on my laptop. 
Today I noticed that I can't create files on the other partitions of the disk. Everything is fine on the Ubuntu partition. Running `fsck` on that partition returned

`fsck from util-linux 2.28.2`

and nothing more.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the recent Windows update. Everything seems to be fine a few days ago.

Comment: Are "the other partitions" Windows/Ntfs partitions, or ext3/4 ?

Comment: @SorenA Windows partitions

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered that in Windows 10 the Fast Startup option is turned on again. Switching it off fixed the problem!

Comment: Some Windows updates do that.